# Configurar dio (o cualquier otro paquete) de forma global en Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Primera vez que utilizo Dart/Flutter. Tengo dos archivos .dart:

- main.dart
- MyHomePage.dart

Utilizo el paquete [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) para las solicitudes HTTP, y le agrego un header adicional que necesito enviar en cada solicitud por medio de un *interceptor*:

```
Dio dio = new Dio();
dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
    onRequest:(RequestOptions options) async {
      options.headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
    })
);
```

Hasta aquí todo en orden, sin embargo, he notado que **debo incluirlo en cada archivo .dart que tengo**. Sé que podría crear una clase común e importarla, o utilizar alguna especie de helper, basándome en la forma como se haría normalmente en otros lenguajes, pero me pregunto si **hay una mejor forma de hacerlo, tal vez propia de Flutter/Dart** y que yo no conozca al ser la primera vez que lo uso.

Comment: de momento yo tampoco hallé una mejor manera que hacerlo con un helper...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un archivo que se llame `default_headers.dart` que content lo siguiente:

```dart
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

final defaultInterceptor =
    InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (RequestOptions options) async {
  options.headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
});
```

Entonces en tus archivos donde tengas conexión http, puedes incluir el header directamente así:

```dart
import 'default_headers.dart';
...

    Dio dio = new Dio();
    dio.interceptors.add(defaultInterceptor);
```

Comment: Sí, algo así es lo que hago, solo que no me parece práctico, lo considero una limitante del lenguaje.

Comment: hmm como lo harías en otro lenguaje?  Podrías crear también un singleton de Dio y usarlo en cualquier lado